# getting the wrong answer for separating a differential equation

Tags: differential

Here is the equation $$ x^5 ye^{y^2}y' = 1  $$

Separating x and y I get : $$ ye^{y^2}\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{x^5} $$

Then:

$$ \int{ye^{y^2}dy} = \int{\frac{1}{x^5} dx} $$

Then integrating both sides I get:

$$ \frac{e^{y^2}}{2}=\frac{-1}{4x^4} +C $$

This is my attempt, am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: your answer is correct

Comment: Except your second equation should have $\frac{dy}{dx}$, not $\frac{dx}{dy}$ but it was separated correctly so I assume it was just a typo.

Comment: The title is confusing: how do you know you got the "wrong answer"?

Comment: According to the online test its incorrect

Comment: What does the test say is the correct answer?

Comment: It doesn't say. It will only tell me my answer is correct or incorrect. I guess i'll just neck myself.

Comment: There are various ways of rewriting the answer you have - is it looking for a formula for $y$ in terms of $x$, for example? Or does it want you to clear fractions?

Comment: @Jai Perhaps you should submit it as $y = \pm\sqrt{\ln\left(2\left(C_0-\frac{1}{4x^4}\right)\right)}$

Comment: or the clear function is $$y=\pm\sqrt{\log(C-\frac{1}{2x^4})}$$